# how can I really change the values of specific text file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

all
I have a txt file with many columns with no headers.
I use

```
    df=pd.read_csv('a.txt',sep=' ',header=None,usecols=[2,3],names=['waiting time','running time')
```

suppose the columns would be like this:

```
      waiting time  running time
0       8617344       8638976
1       8681728       8703360
2       8703488       8725120
3       8725120       8725760
4       4185856       4207488
```

for the third column, I want to subtract values of the second columns, then I can get

```
    waiting time  running time
0       8617344         21632
1       8681728         21632
2       8703488         21632
3       8725120           640
4       4185856         21632
```

My question is that how let change really happen in txt file? It means the txt file has been really changed correspondingly.

Comment: `df['running time']=df['running time']-df['waiting time']`

Comment: Actually that would not reflect in the txt file. I want the correponding content in txt file  also to be changed

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how to update the text file with your new data, you just use the write version of your first line:

```
# Save to file a.txt
# Use a space as the separator 
# Don't save the index
df.to_csv('a.txt', sep=' ', index=False)
```